# When an XPath's target element is specified by ID, can other parts have any effect on the speed or efficiency?

Tags: xpath, browser

Suppose that a document contains a large amount of elements. For example, elements with the species name structured like the phylogenetic tree. The `div` with the `id="dog"` is a descendant of the `div` with the `id="carnivora"`.

In this case, is it any faster/more efficient to try to locate dog with `//div[@id='carnivora']//div[@id='dog']` (which limits the search area to only the carnivora element and its descendants) instead of just `//div[@id='dog']`? Or is even `//div[@id='dog']` (which limits the search target types to only `divs`, not something like `span`, etc) faster/more efficient than `//*[@id='dog']`?

Comment: More specific expressions should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `//div[@id='dog']` has `O(N)` complexity, while `//div[@id='carnivora']//div[@id='dog']` ~ `O(N^2)`, where N is a total number of divs. Maybe not `N^2`, maybe `N*logN`.

I've created an xml file, 25000 lines

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <!--10-->
    <div id="carnivora">
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
        <div id="dog"/>
    </div>
</doc>
```

and run two xpaths ontop of it:

- `//div[@id='carnivora']//div[@id='dog']` – 8 sec
- `//div[@id='dog']` – 0.1 sec

Comment: Isn't it illegal that there are duplicate ID's?

Comment: It is, ID must be unique. But for our experiment it doesn't matter.